# codeigniter get prev and next blog page link

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to create a function in model that retrieve the prev and next links of certain blog post page. Blog posts are saved in database in a table where are different types of pages, so the ID's are not in order. 
What I achieve so far is getting an array with all the pages that are "marked" as blog posts.
To make it clear, here is the array:

```
Array
(    

   [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2127
            [options] => news=on
        )


   [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2133
            [options] =>  news=on
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2137
            [options] =>  news=on
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2138
            [options] => news=on
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2139
            [options] => news=on
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2142
            [options] =>  news=on
        )

    [6] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2144
            [options] => news=on
        )

    [7] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2145
            [options] => news=on
        )

    [8] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2146
            [options] => news=on
        )

    [9] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2153
            [options] => news=on
        )

    [10] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2156
            [options] =>  news=on
        )

)
```

I can get the current page ID and I want to get the prev and next ID's, for example when I am on page with ID 2133 I want to get the ID 2127 and 2137.

I already searched and tried some solutions but they didn't worked. 
Please help!

Comment: i think you can say about pagination am i right

Comment: no. i am not talking about pagination. this is the single page for blog post. I want to be able to put links to prev and next article(blog post)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array of StdObjects is called $myArray, you can get an array of the id's with this.

```
$idArray = array();
foreach($myArray as $m=>$o) {
  $idArray[]= $o->id;
}

print_r($idArray);
```

which gives you

```
Array (
    [0] => 2127
    [1] => 2133
    [2] => 2137
    [3] => 2138
    [4] => 2139 
)
```

and you could pull which id's you need from the $idArray.

Answer (score 0):

@ourmandave:
I used your suggestion and finally come up with the entire solution. I'll write it down here in case someone needs id.

```
    // get the all the blog pages 
    $blog_pages = $this->pages_model->get_links();

    $idArray = array();
    foreach($blog_pages as $m=>$o) {
      $idArray[]= $o->id;
    }
    // Find the index of the current item
    $current_index = array_search($current_page->id, $idArray);
    // Find the index of the next/prev items
    $next = $current_index + 1;
    $prev = $current_index - 1;

    // and now finally sent the data to view
    $data['prev'] = $this->pages_model->get($idArray[$prev]);
    $data['next'] = $this->pages_model->get($idArray[$next]);
```